# Python MD5 Cracker "TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required"

Tags: python, python-3.x, md5

My code looks as follows:

```
md = input("MD5 Hash: ")
if len(md) != 32:
    print("Don't MD5 Hash.")
else:
    liste = input("Wordlist: ")
    ac = open(liste).readlines()
    for new in ac:
        new = new.split()
        hs = hashlib.md5(new).hexdigest()
        if hs == md:
            print("MD5 HASH CRACKED : ",new)
        else:
            print("Sorry :( Don't Cracked.")
```

But, I get this error when I run it:

```
    hs = hashlib.md5(new).hexdigest()
TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required
```

How do I solve this? "b" bytes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whatever the case, by calling [**`split()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on `new` you create a `list` object and not an `str`; lists do not support [the Buffer API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html). Maybe you were looking for [**`strip()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) in order to remove any trailing/leading white space?

Either way, the resulting `str` from `new.strip()` (or `split()` if you select an element of the resulting list) should be *encoded* since unicode objects must be [encoded before feeding it to a hashing algorithms' initializer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hash-algorithms).

```
new = new.strip() # or new.split()[index]
hs = hashlib.md5(new.encode()).hexdigest()
```

Comment: 'new=new.strip()'
to delete these space but don't working why?

Comment: If you're working with Pandas, having null (NaN) values can cause this error too, so you may need to handle those values before you run them through.